# python match case - compare to result of a function return

Tags: python, match

i'm using pysimplegui with an event-listener loop, comparing the event against a function return. the functions return strings - can i use match instead?

something like this:

```py
window = main_window()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event == keys_and_strings.GO_SHIP_KEY():
            return process_shipments()
```

```
def BOXES_KEY(shipment):
    return f'-{shipment.shipment_name_printable.upper()}_BOXES-'.upper()
```

i wanted to change to using match case statements because, well, they're prettier?

so i tried eg:

```
    match event
        case keys_and_strings.BOXES_KEY(shipment_to_edit):
            package = boxes_click(shipment_to_edit=shipment_to_edit, window=window)
```

but got `(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('called match pattern must be a type'), <traceback object at 0x00000277B66FA4C0>)`

so after some googling i tried:

`match event: case [keys_and_strings.BOXES_KEY(shipment_to_edit)]:`

but that failed.

so how can i use match case to compare event to the result of a function call, where the function returns a string?

and what are the pros and cons of match vs if/else?

thanks!

Comment: `match/case` is for matching structural patterns, not for equality tests like `switch/case` in C/JS/PHP.

Comment: Could you provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: It's nice you asked about the pros and cons. I like you're looking for insight, not just an answer. One downside is using a language feature like match shrinks the size of the potential users that can use your code.  Using `match` means your users have to run Python 3.10 and greater. Looking at the [PyPI stats for all packages](https://pypistats.org/packages/__all__) 71% of users are using < 3.10. Those people will not be able to run your code. IMO, chaces are low your code will convince someone to upgrade, so they'll pass.

Comment: But of course - I'm here to learn not to get you guys to do my work... Good point about versions. I guess I'm still at the stage where I'm rightfully doubtful that anyone but me will be running the code, and by the time I've cleaned it up enough they might we'll be talking about python 4 

Comment: I presume the OP is the one who wants to use his code, @MikefromPSG, not "others". It's like you're advocating that no-one should use a recent version of Python for no other reason than it's recent. There are plenty of corporate Python users who find it hard to upgrade due to the obtuseness of management processes. I know some who are still on Python 2.7. Let's not drag the chain.

Comment: Stated a set of facts while answering the specific question asked:  "what are the pros and cons of match vs if/else?"   No advocation, no chain dragging here.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, `match` is not just a "prettier" way to write if/else. Rather it compares structures.

```
def foo(): return "foo"

match "foo":
  case foo():
    print("foo!")
```

Is not merely synonymous with:

```
def foo(): return "foo"

if "foo" == foo():
  print("foo!")
```

However, the following would work:

```
match "foo":
  case str(): print("foo!")
```

We have matched the case where the value being matched is a `str`. This is why your error says that the match pattern must be a type.

If you want to, you can use pattern matching to bind names to values. E.g.

```
def foo(x):
  match x:
    case str(s): print(f"String {s}")
    case int(n): print(f"Int {n}")
```

You can "or" patterns together with `|` but beware that any names bound must be matched by all of the patterns that are joined with `|`.

Comment: awesome, thanks for explaining - showing how it could be forced to work is instructive as to why i shouldn't!! is there any other syntax to avoid repeating many iterations of "elif [value] == ...", or to group a series of if/else statements somehow?

Comment: Yes... take a look at the [Dispatchers Demo Program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Dispatchers.py) for examples of other ways to handle event processing.

Comment: Thanks @MikefromPSG that's perfect. I actually paid for the tutorial course last year I'll go find the specific video and rewatch...are you the tutorial Mike? And the maker of the library too? Thanks so much for all your work, let alone offering support on rando so questions! Big respect ❤️

Comment: Glad to be of help!  Same Mike in all cases. There's, perhaps thankfully, only one me. Thank you so very much for the kind words. I'm glad you're enjoying learning and using PySimpleGUI. It's rewarding to help people build whatever they imagine. Right back at ya with the big respect. 

Answer (score 0):

You are completely misusing `match-case` construciton here and getting it confused with `switch-case`. `switch-case` is an alternative way to write `if-else`, but `match-case` is used for *pattern matching*. You can write something like this

```
match event:
    case "AMAZON_BOXES-":
        ...
    case "GOOGLE_BOXES-":
        ...
```

or this

```
while True:
    match window.read():
        case ("something_1", values):
            print(values)
        case ("something_2", values):
            print(values)
```

But there're most simplistic usages of `match-case`. In your scenario these constructions may be applicable (depending on the context).
I advise you to read some guides on `match-case`. I personally can recommend section "Pattern matching with Sequences" in Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho.